# Can I depend on all Start methods being run before any Updates at scene load?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am experimenting with a unidirectional data flow from a Manager object down into the components which it manages, and I need to know if I can trust that, for any objects present in the Scene at load time (those which are in the Scene Hierarchy in the editor), ALL of their `Start` methods will be called before ANY of their `Update` methods are called.

The documentation on MonoBehaviour.Start() says the following:

> Start is called on the frame when a script is enabled just before any
>   of the Update methods is called the first time.

This certainly insinuates that what I am asking is correct, but it could just be odd wording. All my tests have shown that this is how it works, but I still want to verify before I start using this pattern everywhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, all your Start methods will run first, and you can look at Awake as well if you are dependent on these methods.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Side question: Can I guarantee that if a component hold other components as properties, that THOSE components' Start methods will run first?

Comment: i remember seeing comments like this (that its not always 100% sure)  http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/is-this-for-real.7892/#post-58314 *quite old thread but didnt find others right now..

Comment: Okay. Thanks! Wondering how to mitigate that.